# How can I sort out this data?

Tags: python, regex, perl, sed

http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/6649/workspace1001.png
[big version](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/6649/workspace1001.png)

I have this product data in a csv file, but some of the fields are wrong.
Look at the screenshot. Some of the images are like this:
image.jpg#foobar

When they need to be
image.jpg

Not all of them have this. They are all .jpg

Is there something I can do in Sed or Python/Perl to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i.bk -e 's/jpg#[^,]*/jpg/g' filename
```

Comment: This borks the rest of my data. It uses commas for delimiters, and quotes for text.

Comment: @user736253: i considered that comma as the delimiter for csv files. if it is something else, put it the place of comma here:`[^,]`

Answer (score 0):

So all you want to do is strip the #... from column S, the image column right?

Perl can do this neatly. Handles quoted cols in CSV and only updates the columns you specifiy.

```
my $in = IO::File->new( "<old.csv" );
my $out = IO::File->new( ">new.csv" );
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();
while( my $rec = $csv->getline($fh) )
{
    $rec->[18] =~ s/\#.*$//s;
    $csv->print( $row );
}
```